# How to get page to automatically refresh when "bad gateway" pops up? (APEX ORACLE)

Tags: oracle-apex

So I have 3 laptops that have a page open basically 24 hours a day. They have queries that are running on the page and all 3 will randomly at one point during the day return a "502 bad gateway the proxy server received an invalid response..."

I think the servers just get overwhelmed at certain parts in the day, usually happens in the morning (when everyone is coming into work), and random times throughout the day. My 'fix' of it was to have the page refresh every hour, then changed to every 30 minutes, but obviously that did not work...

Is there any way to have it when the page returns a '502 bad gateway' error to automatically refresh? (Can't install any plugins on google chrome/microsoft edge/etc due to work settings)

The queries take a short amount of time to load as well, when I first open the page it only takes around 10 seconds for the page to be fully loaded, so i don't think it's long running queries issue.

Also, all I have to do is refresh the page and they are fixed and work back to normal, but it would be nice if that can just be done automatically.

Comment: The error is being returned by the server; it's just another page as far as the browser is concerned. There's no code on that page and no awareness or automation in the browser to handle that exception. Only solution I can see (have been in a similar position myself in past years) is a manual refresh of the page URL to reload its original code.